# My Mongoose Database is not connectin to my javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I Am Making A Discord Bot and i am stuck my database is not connecting here is the code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Database } = require("../../config.json");



module.exports = {
    name: "ready",
    once: true,
    /**
    * @param {Client} client
    */ 
    execute(client) {
        console.log("O Bot X Leci Na Discorda !")
        client.user.setActivity("Twitch", {type: "STREAMING", url: "https://www.twitch.tv/olekiox"})

        if(!Database) return;
        mongoose.connect(Database, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUndenifiedTopology: true
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("O Bot X Jest Połączony Z Databasem ")
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
}
```

idk what is wrong help pls

Comment: replace `Database` with your mongodb connection string, what do you get?

Comment: have you actually called execute function? it seems like you have only exported it.